Kotlin: Is it possible to change the way string templates are evaluated?
This is purely a theoretical question, but I'm wondering, whether it's possible to change the way objects are serialized in string templates like in "value: $value"?
With the research I've done so far, this seems to not be possible, but the syntax I had in mind would be something like Context.run { "value: $value" }, where the context may decide how value is serialized (e.g. special treatment for certain classes, escape strings).
Applications would for example be uri builders or any other context which requires encoding. No more "https://www.example.com/?${key.toString().urlEscape()}=${value.toString().urlEscape()}", just UrlBuilder.run{ "https://www.example.com/?$key=$value" } where urlEscape is applied to all arguments by the url builder.
I'm really just curious about syntax improvements, I don't have an active issue without workaround.

As a general rule. changing the syntax of a language just to reduce typing is a Very Bad Idea.    Do you think the meaning would be clear to others reading the code?

I think it can be achieved with extension function.

@TimRoberts That's a very good point Tim, I haven't considered that. It would certainly require more mental load when reading the code if language constructs are context specific. When using an implicit receiver in general, this usually just changes the members/functions in the current namespace, so normal language constructs do not change. Considering this, it may even be a desired effect that the syntax has to change.  Please feel free to add something like this as an answer so I can approve it. :)

@MamoonAsad Yes, I currently achieve this by defining a context object with extension functions. Something like interface UrlBuilder { companion object {}; fun Any.encode() = toString().urlEncode() }} and then UrlBuilder.run { "https://www.example.com/?${key.encode()}=${value.encode()}" }

This is not possible. From the Kotlin Language Specification.

An interpolated value v is converted to kotlin.String according to
the following convention:
If it is equal to the null reference, the result is "null"; Otherwise,
the result is v.toString() where toString is the kotlin.Any
member function (no overloading resolution is performed to choose this
function in this context).

So you cannot control this in any other way than to override toString in the class of the interpolated value.

Are you sure we can do this with KSP? I believe KSP can only add new code, we can't replace or modify an existing implementation of foo. We would rather need a custom compiler plugin maybe (?).

@broot To be honest, I am not actually sure.

Its partially possible, meaning you can substitute your own custom interface inside the block to force the compiler to bind differently, however unless you needed to reuse the same few variables a lot (hence worth the boilerplate) it's probably not worth doing.
